# calling method from Angular2 template results in NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, methods

I would like to call a method from the template, but the call results in NG0100.

How shall I do this properly in Angular2 ?

This is the ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

    public getRandom(): number {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

This is the template:

```
<p>Here is a random number: {{ getRandom() }}</p>
```

This is the minimal demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yuaqfr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pipes in Angular, for example:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'random'
})

export class RandomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
     return (value + Math.random());
  }
}
```

And in the html:

```html
<p> {{ 'Here is a random number: ' | random }}</p>
```

You should declare Pipe same as component.

```js
declarations: [
.
.
RandomPipe
],
```

Comment: Thank you! Although Andres' solutions also work, I chose your pipe based solution because that seems to be the less invasive in my scenario (I am an Angular beginner fiddling with a rather big system).

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs change detection by default whenever something change, if you change the value after Angular hasn't finished running the detection, you will get this error, I think you only see this message in `dev` environment, not on `production`.

You can solve this by following these 2 approaches in my opinion:

Changing the detection strategy `OnPush`, there is a good article about this [here](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  getRandom(): number {
    return Math.random();
  }
}
```

Or using the lifecycle hook `ngOnInit` for assigning a value to `random`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  random: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.random = Math.random();
  }

  getRandom(): void {
    this.random = Math.random();
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<p>Here is a random number: {{ random }}</p>
<button (click)="getRandom()">Random</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the two valid solutions! In my real scenario I have a lot of items (records) from multiple sources. I need to assign a random color for each when displaying them. The ngOnInit based solution works but cumbersome in my case. The onPush detection strategy works great, and the linked article was really useful. But I am a beginner in Angular, so I am a bit worried to change detection strategy to non-default.